# How can I get element values inside an element selected by ID?

Tags: javascript

I read code on element using

```
const elem = document.getElementById("TcHmiRecipeEdit")
console.log(elem);
```

results:
[image]
What code in Javascript I need to use to get values Marked in the photo. I'm starting my adventure with javascript and what we have a huge problem with is actually extracting values from the code as in the example above.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to select an element nested somewhere within the element you're getting by ID?  You might want to take a look at `document.querySelector()` instead, which can take complex selectors rather than only an ID.

Comment: You haven't said how you want to select the heading cell. By index? By text value? Please revise to be more specific. See [ask].

Comment: Arbitrary because I don't know how to refer to a given element.

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` and `querySeletorAll` are suitable for this purpose.

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('#TcHmiRecipeEdit table th').forEach(el => {
    console.log(el.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Spreading a querySelectorAll and mapping the textContent

```js
const thVals = [...document.querySelectorAll('#TchmiRecipeEdit table th')]
  .map(th => th.textContent.trim());

console.log(thVals)
```

```html
<div id="TchmiRecipeEdit" style="inset: 16px;">
  <div class=" TCHES Controls Beckhoff TcHiRecipeEdit template tched-box " tabindex="-1 ">
    <div class="Tched Controls Beckhoff TcHnRecipeEdit-editing pane ">
      <div class="TcHed_Controls Beckhoff TcHndRecipeEdit-editing-box">
        <div class="Tchad Controls Beckhoff TcHniRecipeEdit-editing-area">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>in</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```